# Map a custom portion of 360 degress to an float from 0 to 1

Tags: math, geometry, processing

I'm getting input from `0` to `360` from my sensor. But I want to map things so `340` degrees equals `0` and `20` degrees equals `1`.

I've tried doing things like using the `map` function

```
float myInput = readData();
float  myVar = map(myInput, 0, 360, 0, 1);
```

But that just makes `340` higher than `20`. I think the fact that it goes from `340` to `0` and then to `20` is what's complicating things.  Is there a way to map a custom portion of `360` degrees from `0` to `1` when my lower point would have a higher number than the higher point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your input to a different range first. Something like this:

```java
if(myInput > 180) {
  myInput = myInput - 360;
}
```

That will convert values like `340` to `-20`. So now your input range is `-20` to `20` and you can use the `map` function:

```java
float mappedInput = map(myInput, -20, 20, 0, 1);
```

You haven't said what should happen if your input is outside that range, so you might have to think harder about those cases, but the general approach should work.